# How to add class from text of LI element to UL element

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

```
<li>HOME
   <ul class="submenu">
   <li>TEST</li>
   <li>TEST</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>PROFIL
   <ul class="submenu">
   <li>TEST</li>
   <li>TEST</li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I Want to add text of the li element to ul class like this:

```
<ul>
<li>HOME
   <ul class="HOME submenu">
   <li>TEST</li>
   <li>TEST</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>PROFIL
   <ul class="PROFIL submenu">
   <li>TEST</li>
   <li>TEST</li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I need help, thanks a ton!

Comment: Fix your Shift key, and ask a real question.

Comment: YOU MEAN YOUR ENTIRE CODE HAS BEEN ALL-CAPS AS WELL? YOU NEED A NEW KEYBOARD

Comment: @Joko...I've adjusted your question to make it more readable. If I've changed the question you are asking beyond recognition, please adjust it further.

Comment: sory i just want write it in capital letter

Comment: why this question has so many negative votes???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($('#CHILD').parent('li').length) {
  // yes, parent of CHILD is an <li>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("li > ul")` will give you the `<ul>` that's within an `<li>`.

As a side note, all caps isn't necessary in HTML, nor on SO.

Comment: Yeh i know that i just want to write entire of my question in CAPS sory if it can bother u